# How to change already made control in VS Designer to inherit from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, ide

So the situation is this,

I have a toolstrip that I've created using the VS IDE (VS2013 Standard). I've already done a lot of work to it, eg adding buttons, hooking events etc.

Can I now change this control to inherit from a custom toolstrip class without having to create a custom control and re-do all the work?

I've tried changing the Designer.cs to use the parent class but when I go back to the Form Designer the changes are reversed.

edit:

To try to make things a bit more clear, if your familiar with xCode I am trying to do the equivalent of setting the CustomClass of an IDE object.

Comment: Can you post some of your code you have so far? Also would you mind elaborating on your third paragraph a little bit? Did you just set up the inheritance of the class and it doesn't look different in the designer: `class ChildClass : ParentClass {...}` or what have you tried so far?

Comment: I assume that you have made a UserControl, not a custom control. Add a new inherited UserControl (Add > New Item > Inherited User Control)and copy paste the work done so far. VS will do the requested wire up for you.

Comment: @CalebB I cannot post any code. What I mean by the third paragraph is I went into the Form.Designer.cs file and changed the object type from ToolStrip to ParentToolStrip and when I opened the VS designer the changes would immediately be reversed. The ParentToolStrip is a stub class for now that just has 'class ParentToolStrip : ToolStrip' and an override for the winproc messages.

Comment: @Oliver I did not make any custom controls, and want to avoid that at this stage (maybe its what should have been done to begin with but it wasnt). I added all the toolstrip, buttons, etc all from the visual studio toolbox onto the form.

Comment: Did you rebuild the solution after changing the .cs file? Making changes to the .cs file won't change the .exe file, the file that is run, unless rebuild/recompiled to the .exe file.

Comment: @CalebB No, that was the problem is that I didn't rebuild the project after changing the Designer.cs. The answer below is a great step-by-step. And .exe is not part of this problem, thx for the suggestions anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make changes to myForm.Designer.cs then

1. Close the designer!
2. Change the type of the control's field in *.Designer.cs `private ParentToolStrip myToolStrip;`
3. Change the type in the `new` command `myToolStrip = new ParentToolStrip();`
4. Build the project.
5. Only if the build was successful (!): open the form in the designer.

I have done this many times. It works.

Make sure that any code that might interfere with the designer is checked:

```
if (!DesignMode) {
    // Your code.
}
```

Note that this does not work in the constructor, since the `DesignMode` property is not yet initialized at that time. In the constructor you can test for the design mode like this:

```
bool designMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Can you give me a hint as to what code might interfere with the designer, I'm not familiar with 'DesignMode' (This is my first _major_ C# project). I know I can look it up, but I'm hoping for a more clear concise overview like you have above, not a bunch of reading. Thanks again!

Comment: The WinForms designer might execute property gettes and setters. When working in the WinForms designer, you are in design mode. When you are running your program, you are not.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is known as visual inheritance and you can find a elaborate description of it here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx